# Asp.Net Core streaming large file through DMZ API endpoint to internal facing API without buffering

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, streaming, large-file-upload

I'm looking for suggestions on how to perform non-buffered large file (gigabyte+) uploads from an externally facing Angular app to an externally facing Asp. Net 5.0 Web API endpoint and then on to an internal facing Asp. Net Web API endpoint. I have the first hop from Angular to the externally facing API working fine using guidance from [Upload files in ASP.Net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0), however that only provides half of the solution. I'm able to upload a 2-gig file to the first endpoint without consuming too much memory (I am seeing ~300MB being consumed which is somewhat concerning, but I'll deal with that later). When I do try to stream to the internal endpoint I'm getting *Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component.* when I try to process the stream and write to disk.

Essentially, I'm looking for a way to have the DMZ act as a pass-through or proxy of sorts so that I can stream and store the file safely to an internal file store without exhausting server memory resources.

Below is C#, html and Typescript for my Angular to the DMZ endpoint flow -- I'm at a loss where to go from there. Any suggestions on how I can make this work without consuming too much memory or CPU?

My client code is quite simple at the moment

**HTML**

```html
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <input type="file" #file placeholder="Choose file" 
             (change)="uploadFile(file.files)"
             style="display:none;" multiple>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" 
                (click)="file.click()">Upload File</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <span class="upload" *ngIf="progress > 0">
            {{ progress }}%
        </span>
        <span class="upload" *ngIf="message">
            {{ message }}
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Typescript**

```js
public uploadFile = (files) => {
  if (files.length === 0) {
    return;
  }

  let filesToUpload : File[] = files;
  const formData = new FormData();
  
  Array.from(filesToUpload).map((file, index) => {
    return formData.append('file'+index, file, file.name);
  });

  this.http.post('https://localhost:5001/api/upload/uploadFileToInternalAPI', formData, 
        {reportProgress: true, observe: 'events'})
    .subscribe(event => {
      if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress)
        this.progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
      else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
        this.message = 'Upload success.';
        this.onUploadFinished.emit(event.body);
      }
    });
}
```

**C#**

Here's is my DMZ endpoint C# code. Note I'm attempting to support multiple files in a single request.

```
[HttpPost("uploadFileToInternalAPI")]
[DisableFormValueModelBinding] // Passing no parameters to the method essentially does the same thing as this attribute
[RequestSizeLimit(MaxFileSize)]
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = MaxFileSize)]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFileToInternalAPI()
{

    var request = HttpContext.Request;

    // validation of Content-Type
    if (!request.HasFormContentType ||
        !MediaTypeHeaderValue.TryParse(request.ContentType, out var mediaTypeHeader) ||
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(mediaTypeHeader.Boundary.Value))
    {
        return new UnsupportedMediaTypeResult();
    }

    // Setup to get the first section (file) from the request
    var reader = new MultipartReader(mediaTypeHeader.Boundary.Value, request.Body);
    var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();

    // Setup MultipartFormDataContent to post to internal API
    var forwardingContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();

    // Loop and process each section (file) in the multipart request. 
    // Builds up a multi-part request to forward to the internal API
    while (section != null)
    {
        var hasContentDispositionHeader = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse(section.ContentDisposition
               out var contentDisposition);
        if (hasContentDispositionHeader && contentDisposition.DispositionType.Equals("form-data") &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentDisposition.FileName.Value))
        {
            // Get the filename from the section
            var fileName = contentDisposition.FileName.Value.Trim('"');

            // Stream content allows to pass a non-buffered stream
            forwardingContent.Add(new StreamContent(section.Body), "file", fileName);
        }

        section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();    
    }

    // For example only -- Don't create a HttpClient like this in production
    var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5002") };
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

    // *** Here's where things break down - I'm not sure how to 
    //     forward the request onto the backend without consuming
    //     the stream content.
    var response = await client.PostAsync("/internalUpload/upload", forwardingContent);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    // If the code runs to this location, it means that no files have been saved
    return BadRequest("No files data in the request.");
}
```

**Internal API C#**

My Internal API is essneitally the same C# but instead of posting to an endpoint it will write the stream to disk file share.

Comment: By 'non-buffered' you mean, 'streamed' - right?

Comment: @RobertPerry, Correct, my code is attempting to use non-buffered streaming by disabling form binding. Of course, by virtue of the fact I have no arguments on the API method the form binding is skipped. Ideally, I would want to just forward the incoming request directly to my second endpoint and stream from there.